# Customer's Best IT Specialist?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence

I have a award, customers chose me as a best IT specialist.

Is it okay to call it in this way "Customer's best IT Specialist" or it would be better to name it as "Best IT Specialist chosen by customers" or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your both given sentences for the award are correct.

But, I would prefer using "Customer's best IT Specialist"; it sounds pretty good and short.

To avoid passivity and verbosity, do not say: "Best IT Specialist chosen by customers".